# How to deal with Firefox saved passwords when using React Controller Components?

Tags: javascript, firefox, reactjs

I'm following the [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) React pattern inside a login form in my application.

That does work fine when Chrome fills in the stored user/password, as it waits for the page to finish loading before filling the fields.
However, Firefox is stubborn and fills in the fields as soon as they appear: this is not enough to call `onChange` and thus, I can't get the field value inside the component's state.

What's the best way to deal with this behaviour?

Comment: do something on window load maybe? (stab in the dark)

Comment: @JaromandaX not sure how that would play with React. I don't think we have any access to the components data outside of them.

Comment: as I said, stab in the dark

Comment: Precisely (pun intended)